# How to run Python selenium script in jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation

Could anyone describe the steps to run python selenium test on jenkins. python is created in eclipse on windows machine. I want to run my test every time I build my environment.

Please help me to get this started.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have chromedriver plugin,selenium plugin, Shining panda plugin, installed on your Jenkins(Go to Jenkins>Manage Jenkins> plugin's).

Select the step run shell script from PostBuild actions,

If you are using unittest module for writing your test's then, use the below command

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m unittest discover --pattern=test_testcasename.py
```

Please take the reference of the below link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFYsO-xPaE8

Comment: HI kaushik,  I have installed all 3 plugins. But there is no option to run shell script. refer: https://www.screencast.com/t/b7FpgJIIGz    Also where should I store script file so that jenkin can access it.

Comment: Hi, under Build steps you can find execute shell option.

Comment: I added a video to the to explain steps in detail for you...! Please see if it helps..!!

Comment: It ran with a simple command.                                                                                 C:
cd C:\Users\Anand\eclipse-workspace\Program\com\intro
py Hello.py

Comment: Did this fix your issue, @ashishkoli?  If so, please mark @kaushik 's answer as correct.